# Star Wars' multiple "Balance to the Force" questions; what to do with them?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've noticed a couple of questions which seem to ask essentially the same thing:

1. [What Was the Actual Prophecy About Bringing Balance to the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6396/what-was-the-actual-prophecy-about-bringing-balance-to-the-force)

   - Asked Oct 23 '11 at 23:17 by @Tango
2. [How was the Chosen One meant to bring balance to the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/how-was-the-chosen-one-meant-to-bring-balance-to-the-force)

   - Asked Sep 26 '12 at 16:14 by @hammythepig

They seem really similar to me, but I can't tell whether they are dupes or not.

**What should we do wit these questions?**

- Close one as dupe of the other?
- Merge them?
- Leave them?

Comment: THANK YOU for actually taking the effort to ask first. I'm getting severely tired of undupehammering questions that SEEM on the surface like dupes, yet only to people who didn't bother to read carefully or check the nuances of either the question or canon.

Answer (score 3):

I think those two are sufficiently different as to be left alone.

**tl;dr** The questions are asking different things, and none of the answers to one would be a good answer to the other. Let 'em be.

The first linked question, [What Was the Actual Prophecy About Bringing Balance to the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6396/what-was-the-actual-prophecy-about-bringing-balance-to-the-force), is interested in the actual text of the prophecy:

> [I]s the actual prophecy ever stated anywhere? Just how much do we know about what it said? Having just re-watched *The Phantom Menace*, the only clues we get are that it seems to include virgin birth and the high midichlorian count.

[Daryl Brown's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6400/31051) covers that base quite well, and I don't think a good answer to Tango's question (as Daryl's is) would be a good answer to the second question.

That question, [How was the Chosen One meant to bring balance to the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/how-was-the-chosen-one-meant-to-bring-balance-to-the-force), is more about the *interpretation* of the prophecy (emphasis OP's):

> [W]e know that Anakin Skywalker was the Chosen One, but how exactly was he supposed to restore balance?
>
> *[...]*
>
> **What is the meaning of 'balance' when it is said that "Chosen One will bring balance to the Force", and did he fulfill the prophecy?**

Interpreting the meaning of the word "balance" doesn't require knowing the full text of the prophecy, and none of the answers provide it (I don't think; I just skimmed over some of the more text-blocky answers)

Comment: I was going to complain about Bubbanutz's answer to Tango's question, which really doesn't address the intended question; but Kevin went and deleted it while I wasn't looking

Comment: Not really sure *any* of these require knowledge beyond Word of God from Lucas.